# No module named 'bindsnet.network'

Tags: python, neural-network

I am going to use Bindsnet for Spiking Neural Network and I have imported it using

`! pip install bindsnet` in jupyter notebook.

and My Python's version is 3.6.

when I run:

```
from bindsnet.network import Network
```

It returns below error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bindsnet.network'
```

Can you please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: If you are using Congress conda try `!conda install bindsnet`

Comment: @isAif I tried, it doesnt work.

Comment: what was the output from your installation?

Comment: @MiguelTrejo Oh I just found in ends with an error:
Installing collected packages: opencv-python, cython, attrs, toml, pluggy, iniconfig, py, pytest, cloudpickle, gym, bindsnet
  Attempting uninstall: cython
    Found existing installation: Cython 0.25.2
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'Cython'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that using pip install was not successful so I changed the code for installation to :

`!pip install bindsnet --ignore-installed`

and now I can run `from bindsnet.network import Network` with no error.